# Extracting text and links from the html is not working with bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am struggling to get the wikipedia.com and the name "John Martin" in the above text via bs4. I am new to bs4.

```
<div class="section" qualifer="allnames">
  <div class="container container-2">
   <div class="title">
     <h1 class="title1">
       This is a test
     </h1>
   </div>
   <div class="tile3">
     <a class="title4" href="wikipedia.com" title="John Martin">
```

I tried this

```
link = soup.find('div', class_='title4')
link = link.a.text()
print(link)
```

Can someone help? How do I get the links and the names from the above code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Try:

```
link = soup.find_all('a', class_='title4')
for l in link:
    print(l['title'])
    print(l['href'])
```

Output:

> John Martin
>
> wikipedia.com

Comment: Thanks. works. how about the link. I am trying .get() function